# How to check if ScrollView has footer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to use [EGORefreshTableHeaderView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh/blob/master/EGOTableViewPullRefresh/Classes/View/EGORefreshTableHeaderView.m) in my App.

I have different UITableViews in my App. In one of them I have a UIView as a footer, and not in the other one. Check this code in EGORefreshTableHeaderView:

```
- (void)egoRefreshScrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (_state == EGOOPullRefreshLoading) {
        CGFloat offset = MAX(scrollView.contentOffset.y * -1, 0);
        offset = MIN(offset, 60);
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(offset, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
     }
```

As you see the contentInset.bottom is `0.0f`. As a result for the TableView with footer I have problem. How can I check if `scrollView` has footer ?

Then I can say:

```
if(ScrollView has footer)
      bottom = 50;
else
     bottom = 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution that I found until now:

```
CGFloat bottom = 0.0f;
if([scrollView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
    if(((UITableView *)scrollView).tableFooterView)
        bottom = 50.0f;
}
[scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, bottom, 0.0f)];
```